# Will remaining scheduled action fail if an earlier scheduled action fails?

Tags: process-builder, exception, scheduled-action

Based on the process below:

[image]

If the 4th scheduled action throws an exception, will the 5th scheduled action still fire later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each scheduled action time is a separate transaction, and can pass/fail independently of any other.